# Integrating mongodb into an existing NextJS app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

My weekend project is to get a NextJS app up and running so I followed: https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app?utm_source=next-site&utm_medium=homepage-cta&utm_campaign=next-website

Now I want to ad a db to it, and I haven't used mongo enough so I decided to use that. I did a search on adding mongodb to a next app, but they seem to start at the beginning with a command like:

```
npx create-next-app --example with-mongodb my-project
```

I could just go back and do it this way, but what if I couldn't.

How do I add mongo to an existing nextJS app?

Comment: The code for the `with-mongodb` example project is available here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb.

Comment: And the official doc from Mongo side: https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/nextjs-with-mongodb/. Are you already able to install Mongo on your machine?

Comment: Yeah, I have Mongo installed. I just ended up diffing the results of a new project created with the with-mongodb flag, then adding what was missing and I was off and running.

Comment: Hey, what command did you end up using? I'm also trying to integrate mongodb to an existing nextjs application

Comment: @WinnieNyambura I just abandoned it all together :/ It was just a little learning experiment. Maybe I'll take another stab at it this weekend. If there is any success, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

npm i mongodb

to use,

import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

[enter link description here](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/integrating-mongodb-to-nextjs-f7038f90051a)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).